# Preventing laravel website from bot attack

Tags: laravel, security, amazon-ec2, server

Recently, I started noticing growth in traffic in my laravel e-commerce website. Fake users(bots) are registering and because of bot attack, server is overloading and crashes. My site is hosted on AWS EC2.
What can can i do to prevent my site from bot attack and save server load.

Comment: Laravel has a "verify" method now so if you sign up you have to "verify" via email.

Comment: You can enable the throttle for all your route, 
I gave an answer below and also you can use cloudflare to prevent bot/ddos attack from the dns

Answer (score 2):

Laravel throttle is a rate limiter for the Laravel application. A rate limiter is a process to check too many requests in a certain time by the user session or IP and respond HTTP status 429 too many requests.

By default, throttle is available in the latest version of laravel
(from 5.2), you can see it on `kernel.php` :

```
'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
```

If `throttle` is not availble on your app, then you can install it from [here](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle)

You can make your request safe implementing laravel throttle by route group like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:60,1'], function () {
  Route::get('your_route', 'YourController@your_method');
  Route::post('your_route2', 'YourController@your_method2');
});
```

or

```
Route::middleware('throttle:60,1')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/user', function () {
    //
  });
});
```

Here 60 requests allowed in every 1 minute by a single user or session IP. You have to test it on a live server. It would not work in localhost.